# problems with dynamic content in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular to operate on table and I have a button to delete a row. I have also written a directive to it. The problems is when I add some new rows dinamically also using Angular the buttons don't work. I read a little bit about it and found out that I should use $compile, so I did. But something is wrong and doesn't work. Here comes the plunk which, I hope, will clarify my problem:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gV1VZjCX6zRheno6rTjr?p=preview)

could you tell me how to make it work?

Comment: That isn't a very "angular" way of doing things like that. In angular you'd want to use a repeater and a data source to control multiple items like that. But, the reason your remove button doesn't work on new items is that you aren't binding the function to the new items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a mistake in $compile. You simply compile wrong html element here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/icNjiQYoyGX0TMKdoR92?p=preview)